# Javascript to change html div class

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Can someone help me out. I'm attempting to createChrome extension that changes the div class on page load. Based on what I'm reading I would need to create a Javascript loop that changes the following div class:

Current: `div class="article-holder article-holder--less"`

Change: `div class="article-holder article-holder--more"`

If anyone can provide how to successfully accomplish this task, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a certain class to a DOM element using `.className`

e.g. `myElement.className = "article-holder article-holder--more"`

Please check the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/className

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the class from the element's list and add the new one in its place.

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.article-holder--less')].forEach(e => {
  e.classList.remove('article-holder--less');
  e.classList.add('article-holder--more');
})
```

```css
.article-holder--less { color: red; }
.article-holder--more { color: green; }
```

```html
<div class="article-holder article-holder--less">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add an `id` to your div:

```js
document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.remove('article-holder--less');

document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.add('article-holder--more');
```

```html
<div id="MyElement" class="article-holder article-holder--less"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically, your extension should :

- get all concerned tags with `document.getElementsByClassName`('article-holder--less')
- loop on it : for each tag, do a div.className = div.className.`replace`('article-holder--less', 'article-holder--more')

Something like (not tested) :

```
var elms = document.getElementsByClassName('article-holder--less');
var div;
for (var i = 0; i< elms.length; i++) {
    div = elms[i];
    div.className = div.className.replace('article-holder--less', 'article-holder--more');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use jquery for this.

```
     $( document ).ready(function() {
     $(".article-holder").attr("class", "article-holder article-holder-more");
     });
```